# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am self studying calculus and cant solve this question:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+k}}$$

I thought that I could calculate this limit as integral $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{k}{n^3}}}$$

but it would work if there was $\frac{k}{n}$ not $\frac{k}{n^3}$

Comment: Your finite sum is this here $$\zeta \left(\frac{1}{3},n^3+1\right)-\zeta \left(\frac{1}{3},n^3+n+1\right)$$

Comment: Intuitively, it seems like this should converge to 1, since $k \ll n^3$ for all $k$ and so you are effectively have something close to $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}$. You can probably formalize it with a little more work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all $k\le n$, $$\frac1{n+1}<\frac1{\sqrt[3]{n^3+k}}<\frac1{n}$$

and

$$\frac n{n+1}<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt[3]{n^3+k}}<1.$$

---

Using the Riemannian integral trick, with $m:=n^3$,

$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac k{n^3}}}=n^2\frac1m\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac k{m}}}\sim n^2\int_{1/n^3}^{1/n^2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}}\to1.$$

Comment: Downvoter, please justify.

Comment: Can you prove that it converges to 1?

Comment: @Kate: this is done.

Comment: wow really nice to see how Rieamannian trick is applied here. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Kate: yep, $k/n^3$ is in $[1/n^3,1/n^2]$, which goes shrinking.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:
$$ \frac{n}{(n^3+n)^{1/3}} \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(n^3+k)^{1/3}} \le 1. $$
Taking the limit at $n \to \infty$ we see that it converges to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that by

$$n\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+n}}\le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+k}} \le n\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}}$$

then take the limit to conclude by squeezy theorem.

As an alternative by first order approximation we have

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{k}{n^3}}}=1+O\left(\frac{k}{n^3}\right)$$

then

$$\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{k}{n^3}}}=\frac1n+O\left(\frac{k}{n^4}\right)$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{k}{n^3}}}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n+O\left(\frac{k}{n^4}\right)=1+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \to 1$$

Comment: this problem is given in the first chapters and I dont know you deduced that

Comment: How do you conclude that the series diverges ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes I did a mistake, now fixed!

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes indeed I was wrong with that. Now it should be fine.

Comment: @Kate Are you allowed to use Taylor's series or at least first order approximation.

Comment: @user No, this is first chapter that covers sequences.

Comment: @Kate Ah ok, therefore squeeze theorem is a better way. I add that way too